# Check if element has class

Tags: javascript

Trying to find a way to display a console.log when a div is clicked. I am trying do do a simple game, if you click on the right box, you will get a message that you won.

as of now I am struggling with the bottom of my code, this part in particular:

```js
function winningBox(){

 if (boxes.hasClass){

  console.log('you win');
 } else {
  console.log('you lose');
 }
}
winningBox();
```

How do I get this to work? if box clicked has class of 'winning' the message should console.log winning. Please take a look. By the way I need to complete this on Vanilla JavaScript

```js
//cup game
//add three cups to screen
//select li element
var button;
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var array = [];
console.log('working');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  document.addEventListener('click', winningBox);


  //shuffle li elements, and ad an id
  function test(boxes) {
    var randomBox = boxes[Math.floor(Math.random() * boxes.length)];
    array.push(randomBox);
    console.log('randombox:', randomBox);
    randomBox.classList.add('winning');

  }
  console.log(test(boxes));


  //user can click on a cup to see if correct
  function winningBox() {

    if (boxes.hasClass) {

      console.log('you win');
    } else {
      console.log('you lose');
    }
  }
  winningBox();

  //if cup is incorrect, display message
  //if correct, display won message
  //button to restart game
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.main {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <container class="main">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </container>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Element.classList.contains` function to check if specified class value exists in class attribute of the element.

So assertion should look like:

```
if (boxes.classList.contains('winning')) {
```

**UPD**
As Karl Wilbur noticed in the comments to my answer, `boxes` is a NodeList instance.

So, you have to convert it into array:

```
var boxes = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

and you will be able to iterate over it:

```
boxes.some(function(el) {
    return el.classList.contains('winning');
});
```

this should return true if at least one of the boxes contains a class name 'winning'.

Comment: yes, it's giving me some type of error....

Comment: So how about telling us exactly what the error message is?

Comment: cannot read 'contains' of undefined

Comment: If `boxes.classList` is `undefined` then you are likely looking at `boxes` as an array of elements. You might need to iterate `boxes`.

Comment: `classList.contains('class_name')`  worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check each container (not an array as in previous answer):

```
function checkawinner(box) {
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if (box.classList.contains('winning')) {
        console.log('you win');
    } else {
        console.log('you lose');
   }
  }, false);
}

for (index = 0; index < boxes.length; ++index) {
  checkawinner(boxes[index]);  
}
```

A pen with "alerts": http://codepen.io/VsevolodTS/pen/BKBjpP

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
//user can click on a cup to see if correct
function winningBox(){
    // ensure that we are not working against a cached list of elements
    var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(i=0,len=boxes.length;i<len;i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.classList.contains('winning')){
            console.log('you win');
        } else {
            console.log('you lose');
        }
    );
}
```