# Javascript document event on certain css class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm used to writing in jQuery for selecting by class, however the following I can't quite get the code right. This lives on every page and should just intercept links with the class 'download-link'. The following works for all links. But i want to target it just for download-link css.

```
 document.onclick = function (e) {
                e = e ||  window.event;
                var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

                if (element.tagName == 'A') {
                    window.open(element.href, "_blank", "location=yes,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top");
                    return false; 
                }

            };
```

I can't quite work out the selector for my if statement to change element.tagName to be element.class or similar.

Heres the last thing I tried

```
 document.getElementById("download-link").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        window.open(e.href, "_blank", "location=yes,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top");
return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: `getElementById`  does not get the elements with the **class** `download-link`. it gets the element with the **id**. If you want to get the elements with a certain class, you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: `if (element.tagName == 'A' && element.classList.contains('download-link')) {` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615762/7733026)

Answer (score 4):

You mention

> should just intercept links with the class 'download-link'

though use `.getElementById()`. You can use `.querySelectorAll()` with selector `".download-link"` and `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` to perform a task, see [forEach method of Node.childNodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108712/foreach-method-of-node-childnodes). For example,  attach an event listener, to each `".download-link"` element

```
document.querySelectorAll(".download-link")
.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // do stuff
  })
})
```

If [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) is not defined at browser you can use `for` loop to achieve same result

```
for (var i = 0, nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".download-link");
      nodes && i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // do stuff
        })
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more clear what the OP did wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: @JamesDouglas The original Answer did mention what was incorrect, and provided code for how to correct the issue. Updated post for further clarity nonetheless

Comment: Thank you - however It doesn't seem to be selecting for me on this code

Comment: @TMB87 What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be selecting"? At which browser are you trying code?